# How to find the lengh of the fields in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question on pyspark dataframe. I have defined a nested dataframe like the below. How to calculate the number of fields here of the dataframe here. In my understanding the number of fields are 5.

```
    schema = StructType(
      [
        StructField('feat_1', TimestampType(), False),      
        StructField('feat_2', StringType(), False),   
        StructField('feat_3', StringType(), False),
        StructField('feat_4', StringType(), False),
        StructField('feat_5', ArrayType(schema_sub_1), False)             
      ]
    )

  schema_sub_1 = StructType(
      [
        StructField('level_1', StringType(), False),            
        StructField('level_2', DoubleType(), False),
        StructField('level_3', DoubleType(), False),    
        StructField('level_4', ArrayType(schema_sub_2), False)    
      ]
    )
    

        colNames = ['Feat_20']
        schema_sub_2 = StructType(
          [
            
            StructField('field_1', StringType(), True),     
            StructField('field_2', StringType(), True),   
            StructField('field_3', StringType(), True),  
            StructField('field_4', StringType(), True),  
            StructField('field_5', StringType(), True),    
            *[StructField(item, DoubleType(), False) for item in colNames]                 
            
          ]
        )
     

The error I get here is :
element in array field tsfresh_feature_set: Length of object (2) does not match with length of fields (4)
```

My question here is, how to find the length of the fields in the pyspark dataframe that we need to create. My assumption is lenght of the fields is 5 (all field_1, fields_2 etc) in . But it displays as 4?

How to find the correct length of the fields?

Comment: The reason for this error, your data and schema doesn't align with each other.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "number of fields" or "length of fields"

Comment: @arudsekaberne - Thank you for the suggestion. Yes you are absolutely correct that the data and schema didnt align. Thank you for the pointer.